# How to append data at a particular position of an Array in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

I am getting this data from backend.

```
"choices": [ [ "gender", "Gender" ], [ "age", "Age" ], ["relationship", "Relationship Type"], [ "state", "State" ] ]
```

There is one other value also coming from backend i.e `compareValue = "users"/"group"`

compareValue could be either "users" or "group".

Based on compareValue we need to manipulate the "choices" array. When compareValue is equal to group, we need to delete "relationship" element and when compareValue is equal to users, we need to add back "relationship" at same position of the array.

I have written below logic to delete the element, which is working fine. I am able to delete the relationship element successfully.

```
if (compareValue == "group") {
    for (var i=choices.length; i--; ) {
        if (choices[i][0] === 'relationship'){
            choices.splice(i, 1);
        }
    } 
}
```

But I am not able to add back the element to the array(that too at same position as earlier). While adding back the relationship element, we also need to check if it already exists or not. If already exists then no need to add.

Can someone please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an immutable approach, that would looks like so:

```
const modified = choices.map(c => c[0] === 'relationship' ? [c[0], 'mynewvalue'] : c);
```

That results in:

```
[ 
 [ "gender", "Gender" ], 
 [ "age", "Age" ], 
 ["relationship", "mynewvalue"], 
 [ "state", "State" ] 
]
```

Comment: Can we add a filter condition here, like check if relationship does not exists, then only append.

Comment: I don't understand what's the expected output. Could you please provide concrete examples? It's difficult for me to update the answer if all I have is "it's not working'. Do you mean: If array contains no item with key "relationship" I want to add a new pair wir ["relationship", "newvalue"]?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting from an array and adding back to that array, I think it makes more sense to preserve the original array and create a filtered version of it based on the current value of `compareValue`.

If `compareValue` is `"users"` then we keep every element including `"relationship"`.  If `compareValue` is `"group"` then we return everything except for `"relationship"`.

```
const filteredChoices = choices.filter(choice => 
  compareValue === "users" || choice[0] !== "relationship"
);
```